# how to list all elements of class when class have foreign key of another class in jdbc servlet jsp mysql?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jsp, servlets, jdbc

How can i to list a class elements in java when class have another class field? 
It looks like this:

```
public class Grad {

private int grad_id;
private **Drzava drzava**;
private String naziv;
private boolean aktivan;
private Set<Korisnik> korisnici = new HashSet<Korisnik>(0);
public Drzava getDrzava() {
    return drzava;
}
public void setDrzava(Drzava drzava) {
    this.drzava = drzava;
}
        public List<Grad> getAllGrad() {

    List<Grad> gradovi = new ArrayList<Grad>();
    try {
        Statement statement = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from grad;");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Grad grad = new Grad();
            grad.setGrad_id(rs.getInt("grad_id"));
        **grad.setDrzava( (Drzava)rs.getObject("drzava"));**/**(HERE IS A     PROBLEM!!)**/
            grad.setNaziv(rs.getString("naziv"));
            grad.setAktivan(rs.getBoolean("aktivan"));
            gradovi.add(grad);
        }




else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listGrad")){
        forward = LIST_GRAD;
        request.setAttribute("gradovi", dao.getAllGrad());
```

This is in jsp page and i think that error is at grad.drzava.naziv:

```
<c:forEach items="${gradovi}" var="grad">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${grad.grad_id}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${grad.drzava.naziv}"/></td> 
                <td><c:out value="${grad.naziv}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${grad.aktivan}" /></td>
```

Exception is: java sql SQLException  Column 'drzava' not found.

Thanks alot for the answer :))

Comment: you might have a table drzava, so you will need to do another select to get the records of that table... filtering it by the 'drzava_id'

Comment: did your grad table have column with drzava?

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from grad;");
```

this returns you the primary key of the "Drzava" table, which is the foreign key in grad table.
So to get the Drzava class object you need to again execute another query like:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from drzava;");
```

then assign the resulting drzava class object to the grad class variable.